# Не работает анимация во фрагменте

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-animation

При переключении на фрагмент не срабатывает анимация

Вот код:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main2, container, false);
    slideUp = contentView.findViewById(R.id.slideup);
    slideDown = contentView.findViewById(R.id.slideDown);
    line_item = contentView.findViewById(R.id.scan_item);
    slideDown.animate().setDuration(DURATION).translationYBy(slideDown.getHeight());

    return contentView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ваша анимация отрабатывает еще до того, как вы что либо увидите на экране, перенесите анимацию в метод `onResume()`.

**UPDATE**

`slideDown.getHeight()` в `onCreate()` вам вернет 0, так же, как и если вы это попробуете сделать сразу в `onResume()`

Повесьте келбек на `Обсервер` в `onCreate()` (или `onResume()` - в зависимости от того как вам угодно) на вашу вью.

```
slideDown.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
```

и в келбеке уже непосредственно отработать анимацию

```
@Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        slideDown.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        slideDown.animate().setDuration(DURATION).translationYBy(slideDown.getHeight());
    }
```

Comment: Я это пробовал. Не помогло.

Comment: @РасулA-ев обновил ответ